# Packet tracer UI zoomed in (double the size)

Tags: 16.04, zooming

I've an issue with some of the programs, packettracer among them, having a zoomed in feel to them and it is eating up screen real estate. Unfortunately I have no idea how to switch to default nor what exactly caused it.

From picture below the icons are bigger than usual, even pixelated. I maximized window to show the extent of it (close, minimize and maximize buttons are visible once mouse is hovering at the menu bar).

Here's an example of what I see: [image: https://imgur.com/a/OibeQ]

Compared to what it should look like: [image: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ll7hB-DitZ0/maxresdefault.jpg]

Please ignore the launcher size --- it is irrelevant to the problem.

Program in question, packettracer was downloaded from [here](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ll7hB-DitZ0/maxresdefault.jpg) and installed from command line. 
Running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with 1920x1080 resolution

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: wording

Comment: Is this a HiDPI system?

Comment: 96 dpi, not HiDPI, if I'm not wront

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also had this issue recently where the icons in packet tracer were over zoomed and pixelated when running in 1920x1080 (only looked right running at 1600x900).

I believe your issue is due to the environment variable, 'QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO=auto' being set in /etc/profile during installation of packet tracer. When running 'env | grep QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO' the variable was set at 2.

For me, commenting this out and rebooting resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the input, wills117!

Comment: Issue persisted on 18.10. Changing the `QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO` to `1` and reboot fixed the issue for me.

Also, on Cisco Packet Tracer 7.2 `libpng12` library is missing, which can be downloaded from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download).

Answer (score 0):

Might be a DPI issue as @muru pointed out. Thank you, btw. When resolution is changed to 1600x900 everything is OK *and* bigger (better for the eyes)

Answer (score 0):

Had the problem that `QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO` resets to auto after reboot. This can be fixed by going to the `/home/user` and adding the line `QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO=1` to the file `.bashrc`